# Ошибка в строках

Tags: c, строки

Я написал программу с использованием строк, но мне выдало ошибку на "strtok" и мне выдало, что strtok устаревший уже. Подскажите чем его можно заменить?(Я пишу в visual studio)/

Answer (score 3):

[`strtok_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), как я понимаю.

Или в самом начале программы написать

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```